# Unit testing react redux thunk dispatches with jest and react testing library for "v: 16.13.1",

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, react-testing-library

I have following function.

```
const loadUsers= () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(userRequest());
    let response= null
    try {
      response= await UserService.getUser();
      dispatch(userLoading());
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(userError(error));
    } finally {
      dispatch(userSuccess(response));
    }
  };
};
```

With the following unit test I was abale to hit the "dispatch(userRequest());"

```
describe('user thunk', () => {
    it('dispatches a userRequest', async () => {
      const dispatch = jest.fn();

      await loadUsers()(dispatch);
      expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userRequest());
    });
  });
```

However I couldn't figure out how to test lines and below `response= await UserService.getUser();`. Even though the function is not complex and I won't have much value for writing complex test, I need it for my pipeline to build.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE-> User Service

```
import axios from 'axios';

const USERS_ENDPOINT = '/user';

export const getUser= async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(PRODUCTS_ENDPOINT, {});
  return response.data;
};

export default getUser;
```

Comment: Where does `UserService` come from? Show the code

Comment: @slideshowp2 updated with UserSerivce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After days of research, I ended up testing the logic the following way.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import * as reactRedux from 'react-redux';

import axios from 'axios';
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

describe('load user thunk', () => {
it('dispatches load user and error on call when API is not mocked', async () => {
  const store = mockStore({});
  const requestDispatch= userRequest();
  const errorDispatch= userError("Mock Message");

  await store.dispatch(await loadUsers());
  const actionsResulted = store.getActions();
  const expectedActions = [
    requestDispatch,
    errorDispatch,
  ];
  expect(actionsResulted.length).toEqual(expectedActions.length);
  expect(actionsResulted[0].type).toEqual(expectedActions[0].type);
  expect(actionsResulted[1].type).toEqual(expectedActions[1].type);
}); 

it('dispatches load user and success on call when API is mocked', async () => {
  const store = mockStore({});
  const requestDispatch= userRequest();
  const successDispatch= userSuccess("Mock Data");
  jest
  .spyOn(axios, 'get')
  .mockResolvedValue({ status: 200, data: "Mock Data"});

  await store.dispatch(await loadUsers());
  const actionsResulted = store.getActions();
  const expectedActions = [
    requestDispatch,
    successDispatch,
  ];
  expect(actionsResulted.length).toEqual(expectedActions.length);
  expect(actionsResulted[0].type).toEqual(expectedActions[0].type);
  expect(actionsResulted[1].type).toEqual(expectedActions[1].type);

 });
```